# Microservices on GCP

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, microservices

I am looking to use GCP for a micro-services application. After comparing AWS and GCP I have decided to go with Google because one major requirement for the project is to schedule tasks to run in the future (Cloud Tasks) which AWS does not seem to offer an equivalent of.

I am planning on containerizing my services and deploying to GCP using Cloud Run with a Redis cluster running as well for caching.

I understand that you cannot have multiple Firestore instances running in one project. Does this mean that all if my services will be using the same database?

I was looking to follow a model (possible on AWS) where each service had its own database instance that it reached out to.

Is this pattern possible on GCP?

Comment: AWS has many options that could be the equivalent of GCP "Cloud Tasks", depending on your particular requirements.  For example, look at [AWS SQS](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/)

Comment: It is my understanding that Cloud Tasks under the hood is really just a managed cron service that is constantly running to see if any tasks need to be fired. I may just implement a Redis instance on AWS that acts as a task queue where a cron job will roll over every minute to see if any dates have expired

Answer (score 1):

Firestore indeed is for the moment limited to a single database instance per project. For performance that is usually not a problem, but for isolation such as your use-case, that can indeed be a reason to look elsewhere.

Firebase's original Realtime Database **does** allow multiple instances per project, and recently added a REST API for [provisioning database instances](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/database-management/rest). Since each Google Cloud Project can be toggled to also be a Firebase project, you could consider that.

Answer (score 1):

> Does this mean that all if my services will be using the same database?

I don't know all details of your case. Do you think that you can deploy a "microservice" per project? Not ideal, especially if they are to communicate using PubSub, but may be an option. In that case every "microservice" may get its own Firestore if that is a requirement.

I don't think one should consider GCP project as some kind of "hard boundaries". For me they are just another level of granularity - in addition to folders, etc.

There might be some benefits for "one microservice - one project" appraoch as well. For example, less dependent lifecycles, better (more accurate) security, may be simpler development workflows...

Comment: This is where my head was at as well. I think for future growth I may just end up going the AWS route to allow for a better separation of concerns without having to create multiple projects.

Comment: Would creating a root collection for each microservice, as a kind of proxy to a schema, be a good design? I'm considering that path too, but are concerned of any drawbacks I'm not aware of at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much detail about your case but you can try below:

Whenever a code is checked in **GitHub** it creates a `docker image` and then pushes it
to **GCR**. Once the image is in **GCR** it gets deployed to **GKE** using **Helm**.
Finally, use your microservices for orchestration and triggering jobs.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).